# Alamofire "installation" not working (red text in Embedded Binaries)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, alamofire

I am trying to add Alamofire to my xcode v6.3.2 project but it's not working for me. I followed all the steps in the readme from the github repo but when I select the framework to add as an "Embedded Binary" it shows with red text and is not available to me in code.

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be? I also tried to add to a brand-new, blank project with the same results.

Comment: Try to use CocoaPods instead is very easy and it's better that install manually in each release of Alamofire

Comment: I tried CocoaPods...you're right that I should try that out. Dependency managers are good. Having issues there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to use CocoaPods. Here is how you do that:

First get Brew. Open up a terminal and paste this in there:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then get CocoaPods. To do that run this command in the same terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

After you've done that navigate to your Xcode project in the terminal (be sure to replace YourProjectHere with your project's name):

```
cd ~/Documents/XcodeWorkspace/YourProjectHere
```

In this folder run the command:

```
pod init
```

After running pod init a file will have been created called: Podfile. Edit this file by typing:

```
vi Podfile
```

At first this file will contain:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'YourProject' do 

end

target 'YourProjectTests' do

end
```

Edit it to contain this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!


target 'YourProject' do

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'

end

target 'YourProjectTests' do

end
```

Now completely exit out of Xcode and run this command in terminal:

```
pod install
```

Last but not least! Type the following command:

```
open YourProjectHere.xcworkspace
```

Everything should be up and running! Make sure to include the following in the class where you'd like to use the Alamofire framework:

> import Alamofire

Comment: CocoaPods seems to be working for me. Thanks really to Victor for the initial suggestion of CocoaPods. I'm newish to iOS (surprised?) and hadn't though about a dependency manager for this. That is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions posted in the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) page and you're right it happens , but even it works too.

Just build the project, and then you can put `import Alamofire` and make requests without problem.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I didn't import? I'll have to try that in a bit.